# My buzzer is just silent on Windows 10. What should I do?

Tags: windows-10, audio, motherboard

So, I've found a buzzer from my PC case box. I've hooked it up to my PC, but only during POST it made any sounds. I tried [beep.exe](https://www.rlvision.com/downloads.php?dl=beep_exe) but no luck. Maybe I need to install some sort of driver?

P.S. My PC specs:

- CPU: AMD Athlon II X2 245 Processor (2.9GHz)
- RAM: 4GB DDR2 800MHz
- Motherboard: Asus M4N78
- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 1809

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: P.P.S: I'll need to install Windows Vista/XP to use that beeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do anything.

The website you downloaded that program from, says this :

> Windows 7 seems to have removed this hardware feature all together for some unknown reason :-(

If PC speaker support was already removed on Windows 7, it won't exist on Windows 10 either.